# Are there perfect conductors which do not display perfect diamagnetism?

Tags: superconductivity, conductors

A superconductor is a perfect diamagnet AND and a perfect conductor.
Are there perfect conductors which are not perfect diamagnets ? Maybe topological insulators ?